# Prime numbers multiplied by 3 shown as prime numbers

Tags: python

I was trying to create a function in Python that checks whether a given number is a **prime** number, so I wrote this code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range(2,x):
            if (x%n)==0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

For some reason, every number which is a sum of (Prime_number*3) is shown as a Prime Number (for example, these are shown as prime numbers: 9,21,15,25...)
Can anyone see a problem with my code?

Comment: This would be a good read for you: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

Because you `return` in the very first iteration of the loop. You can't know that something is prime until after the loop has been exhausted. So don't return `True` until the iterations have finished.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range(2,x):
            if (x%n)==0:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens, because you return from `is_prime` on the very first iteration of the loop. You test if `x` is dividable by 2, return `True` if it is and `False` otherwise.

Remove `else` clause from the loop and return `True` after it has ended.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range(2,x):
            if (x%n)==0:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method would iterate only upto square root of x.

```
import math;
def isPrime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False;
    elif x == 2:
        return True;
    else:
        for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x))+1):
            if x%n == 0:
                return False;
        return True;

# Test the method for first 50 natural numbers
for i in range(51):
    if isPrime(i):
        print i;
```